# Word for "a disk-shaped rubber plate that fits between metal parts to prevent leakage of fluids"

Tags: word-request

What is the word for "a disk-shaped rubber plate that fits between metal parts to prevent leakage of fluids"?

Such a plate has a hole in the middle to allow for the passage of a fluid. The plate's function is to prevent sideways leakage that would otherwise happen when two pieces of metal pipes come together.  For example, the plate found in a flush tank that prevents water from leaking down through the hole at the bottom of the tank while the tank button is unpressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is **gasket**.

From NOAD:

> **gasket** (*n.*) a shaped piece or ring of rubber or other material sealing the junction between two surfaces in an engine or other device.

A gasket can be as simple as a rubber ring, or it can be a very specialized shape that is designed for one particular engine or pump.

This is a gasket kit for a motorcycle engine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Washer"

washer noun
wash·​er | \ˈwȯ-shər,  ˈwä-\
Definition of washer 
1 : a flat thin ring or a perforated plate used in joints or assemblies to ensure tightness, prevent leakage, or relieve friction
2 : one that washes
especially : WASHING MACHINE

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary

I do quite a lot of work putting together furniture.  The directions frequently call for the use of a "washer" so I was familiar with this word immediately.  However, I looked it up and inserted a definition and source in the hopes that this is the *correct* way of responding to a question.